# How to pass an object back from a React Native Android module to Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

React Native's [Native Module documentation for Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#argument-types) says that `ReadableMap` directly maps to a Javascript object. I assume this means that when I pass an object from Javascript to a native module, it is available as a `ReadableMap`.

How do I do the reverse, which is to create a dictionary (mapping string to string) in a native module and return it to Javascript via a [callback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/native-modules-android.html#callbacks)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `WritableMap` to simply pass map values through callback.

```
@ReactMethod
public void pass(Callback cb) {
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put("A", "one");
    hm.put("B", "Two");
    hm.put("C", "Three");
    WritableMap map = new WritableNativeMap();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
        map.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    cb.invoke(map);
}
```

for more complex data, see this [blog](https://medium.com/shoutem/ways-to-pass-objects-between-native-and-javascript-in-react-native-c3dcae7bf4f5).

Answer (score 11):

For `React Native >=0.62`, you can use this:

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;

@ReactMethod
public void test(Callback callback) {
    WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();

    map.putString("yourKey", "yourValue");

    callback.invoke(map);
}
```

To call the native function in React Native, do this:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

NativeModules["replaceWithTheModuleName"].test(res => {
  console.log(res);
})
```

Comment: Simple and nicely